# how to specify class path for java agent

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am write a Java Agent to instrument a target Method of a target Class.

I use the javassist library to do instrument.

So the java agent (let named CnAgent.class) need its dependency : javassist library to run.

The directory hierarchy is :

```
.
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── com
│   └── yet
│       └── another
│           └── test
│               └── agent
│                   ├── CnAgent.class
│                   └── CnTransformer.class
└── lib
    └── javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar
```

and the MANIFEST.MF file content is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar .
Agent-Class: com.yet.another.test.agent.CnAgent
Created-By: 1.8.0_11 (Oracle Corporation)
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

I create jar ball by following command:

```
jar cvfm CnAgent.jar META-INF/MENIFIEST.MF . lib
```

when I load the Agent with Attach API of JVM. 
the error prints :

```
error when transform : javassist/ClassPool
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/ClassPool
```

which means the javassist library cannot be found by agent code.

So my question is :

1. How to set Agent library's class path letting it find the dependencies?
2. Why the Class-Path option in MANIFEST.MF not works , does it only for jar directly ran in command line ?

Thanks your wisdom :)

Comment: Try using `Boot-Class-Path` instead of `Class-Path` (without the dot `.`).

Comment: WARNING: javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar not added to bootstrap class loader search: Illegal argument or not JAR file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the option -Xbootclasspath: (sets the path) or -Xbootclasspath/a: (appends the given path to the existing boot class path) (refer to [doc from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)). But, as described in the link, it is non-standard.

As an alternative, you can copy the missing jar file in the %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext directory.

Answer (score 5):

Per [Guido's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389099/%E1%B4%B3%E1%B5%81%E1%B4%B5%E1%B4%B0%E1%B4%BC) comment above, you should add `Boot-Class-Path` to your agent `MANIFEST.MF`.

See these [`java.lang.instrumentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) docs (Manifest Attributes section)

In my case, I have this in Ant's build.xml:

```
    <manifest file="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
       <attribute name="Premain-Class" value="de.bodden.tamiflex.playout.Agent"/>
       <attribute name="Main-Class" value="de.bodden.tamiflex.playout.Agent"/>
       <attribute name="Can-Retransform-Classes" value="true"/>
       <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${tf.version}"/>
       <attribute name="Boot-Class-Path" value="guava-22.0.jar:guice-4.1.0.jar" />
   </manifest>
```

and then copy the guice and guava jars to the directory I run the command from e.g. `java -verbose:class -javaagent:poa.jar -jar ExampleProject.jar > loaded.txt`

This also lists all the classes loaded to allow you to debug what Java class loader is actually doing.

Neither option from [whiskeyspider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185322/whiskeyspider) worked for my case.